# TouchDown Events of ScatterViewItem never raised

Tags: pixelsense, touch-event, scatterview

I am using Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch Beta. I have a problem to handle the `TouchEvent` of a `ScatterViewItem`.

In my code I create a `ScatterViewItem` and add it to the `ScatterView`. So far no problem.
But I want to handle a `Touch` on this `ScatterViewItem` and it seems that a `TouchEvent` is never raised.

Here is a little code snippet:

```
ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();
item.TouchDown += handle_TouchDown;
GlobalScatterView.Items.Add(Item);

private void handle_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```

If I touch the `ScatterViewItem`, nothing happens.

Can anyone please give me a hint or a code snipet that solves my problem?

Comment: Did you add some content to the ScatterViewItem?  Thats important but not shown in your code snippet

Comment: Yes, I added a UserControl. To solve my problem I used TouchEnter and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ScatterViewItem item=new ScatterViewItem();
item.TouchDown += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(handle_TouchDown);
GlobalScatterView.Items.Add(Item);

private void handle_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```